# Edit meta tags per entity via field or entity property?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

Is there a way in Drupal 8 to override the global meta tags at the entity (node) level when adding or editing content? I thought the option previously existed in 7.x, but I am not seeing it in 8.x.

If not, is there a way to alter the meta tags when preprocessing a node to inject them based on node fields in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

All you need to do is add the Meta tags field to the node types where you want to have this.

Comment: Ah, okay, must have overlooked that. I will check into that.